# Problems with cmake and Qt5 on ubuntu

Tags: qt, cmake, undefined-reference

I am trying to install some software (on my ubuntu system) that uses Qt5 libraries and cmake. When I run the provided cmake file (followed by make) I get
 `/opt/Qt/5.10.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5.10.1: undefined reference to ...` errors.

I suspect these errors have something to do with a warning message I get from cmake for various Qt5 libraries: `runtime library [libQt5...] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in: /opt/Qt/5.10.1/gcc_64/lib`

How would I go about fixing this?
Thanks.

Comment: According to the warning, it seems that you have two QT installed. And linker actually takes a library in a directory, which hides desired one. The most easiest way to fix the problem - remove one of QT installation.

Comment: In addition to @Tsyvarev's anwer, can you post the output of `ldd /opt/Qt/5.10.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5.10.1`? Removing one should definitly fix your issue. I guess one was installed with the package manager, and the other with Qt's installer. The later has `Qt Maintenance Tool`, which let you manage which version are installed easily.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Removing the second Qt installation helped.